# Manually delete GroupMember Record

Tags: soql, data, user-management, queue, userlicense

Would I be shooting myself in the foot if I manually deleted a single record from the GroupMember object that links an *inactive* user to a queue? Is there something that happens when you do it via the UI beyond removing that record?

For more context: why would I do this? There's a known issue where users aren't automatically removed from queues when set to inactive (see [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZxRUAV/automatically-take-users-out-of-queues-when-made-inactive) for the Salesforce idea to make it a feature). They don't show in the list of users in the queue because they're inactive. That's my situation. The solution is to activate the user, remove them from the queue, and then deactivate them again. BUT...there are no licenses left in the org, so I can't activate them.

I do know the exact record in the GroupMember table - there's only one record in GroupMember for that UserOrGroupId (UserId in this case), so I know the specific record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the system allows you to do so, there's no problem with deleting the group member record through an API or even Execute Anonymous Apex code. Adding or removing users is an efficient operation because of how Salesforce handles group membership. I wouldn't expect any complications from deleting the user from the group. In fact, here's some code you can use to clean up all inactive users from all groups:

```
GroupMember[] members = [SELECT Id FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId IN (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isactive=false)];
delete members;
```

Comment: I ended up going the anonymous Apex route. I'd thought of it after I posted, but before I saw your response, with the same reasoning: it'd throw an error if it shouldn't be deleted. Still wasn't 100% sure, but it seemed reasonable. But if @sfdcfox says it's OK, I believe it. :)